# Unable to start Grails: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: jenkins

I am facing issue in starting Grails from Jenkins Server. It performs all the steps right from fetching the content from SVN repository to final compilation and Building WAR file ...
but at the end it gives me following error as specified in the error log. For your reference I am giving you verions of each product:-

1. Groovy (grails.1.3.7)
2. Ant (apache-ant-1.6.5)
3. IVY Ivy 2.2.0
4. JDK 1.6 (Build 31)

Error Log

BUILD FAILED
/appl/instances/jkshome/workspace/$$JOBNAME/foldername/build.xml:112: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/appl/instances/jkshome/workspace/$$JOBNAME/build/foldername/build.xml:49: Unable to start Grails: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I have spent around week to resolve this but failed to do so. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thank in advance....